# How can my script invoke SSH and avoid "Enter passphrase for key" messages?

Tags: shell, ssh

I have a shell script that includes the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/ssh -q -i /.ssh/id_rsa -l oracle \
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -o PasswordAuthentication=no \
    ${REMOTE_HOST} ${REMOTE_CMD}
```

The StrictHostKeyChecking=no avoids prompting if the remote host isn't recognized, while the PasswordAuthentication=no avoids prompting for passwords if the private key isn't known.  However, if someone accidentally sets a passphrase for the private key, I still get a prompt to "Enter passphrase for key".  This can cause the script to hang while waiting for a response, which is a bad thing.  Is there some way to avoid the prompt and exit immediately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh -o BatchMode=yes ...` will disable passphrase/password querying.